# Why the execution of spark-shell on YARN two times results in pending the second one?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am setting up my Hadoop cluster for testing purposes and I put everything into 3 Docker containers.

My spark-defaults.conf on master are:

```
spark.master                     yarn
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://spark-master:9000/spark/logs
spark.serializer             org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.history.provider          org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs://spark-master:9000/spark-logs
spark.history.fs.update.interval 10s
spark.history.ui.port            18080
spark.driver.memory              512m
spark.executor.memory            512m
spark.yarn.am.memory             512m
spark.yarn.historyServer.address spark-master:18080
spark.executor.instances         1
```

core-site.xml

```
[root@spark-master hadoop]# cat core-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://spark-master:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
        <value>131072</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hadoop</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
[root@spark-master hadoop]# cat yarn-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>spark-master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>4096</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>4096</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
[root@spark-master hadoop]# cat hdfs-site.xml 
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn node -list

```
[root@spark-master /]# yarn node -list
Total Nodes:2
     Node-Id         Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
cassandra-node-1:39414          RUNNING cassandra-node-1:8042                              1
cassandra-node-2:42546          RUNNING cassandra-node-2:8042                              1
```

master

```
[root@spark-master /]# jps
1952 SparkSubmit
597 NameNode
458 ResourceManager
1066 SecondaryNameNode
2906 Jps
75 ZeppelinServer
1292 HistoryServer
2702 SparkSubmit
```

node-1

```
[root@cassandra-node-1 /]# jps
96 NodeManager
1606 CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend
3094 Jps
231 DataNode
```

node-2

```
[root@cassandra-node-2 /]# jps
229 DataNode
3110 Jps
1565 ExecutorLauncher
94 NodeManager
```

All seems to be good here. I see that there is application manager in one container and spark shell executor in another one.

Now the problem is rather simple. All I want to do is to execute spark-shell two times - I wanted to do 
"one spark-shell and one Zeppelin interpreter on yarn" scenario but Zeppelin interpreter didnt work as it was pending indefinitely so for the sake of simplicity I want to just have 2 spark-shells running.

But when I am about to execute the second shell, it is stuck but here is enough resources to use, right? There is 3.13 GB of avail memory, only 1 vcore is used out of 8 (7 vcores free), all seems to be pretty idle so why another spark-shell is not started and it is pending?

For pending application attempt it reports that:

```
Total Outstanding Resource Requests: <memory:896, vCores:1>
```

But I have plenty of memory and CPU does not seem to be issue too.

I have 4 core processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GHz (cat /proc/cpuinfo give 4 processors) however I dont understand why it reports it like I have 8 (maybe because 2 Docker containers so it thinks that I have 2x4 but I have 4 only in total).

Maybe the issue is that one spark shell occupies 2 cores as it uses 2 containers (one for application master, another one for spark executor) and another spark-shell would also use 2, so its 4 together, but it somehow can allocate only three and one is outstanding but why when I have 4 in total?

The first shell starts without problem but the second one is "accepted" but it is waiting for resources and it proceeds only in case I kill the first spark-shell.

EDIT

1) yarn node -list before any application

```
Total Nodes:2
         Node-Id         Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
cassandra-node-2:43961 RUNNING  cassandra-node-2:8042 0
cassandra-node-1:36905 RUNNING  cassandra-node-1:8042 0
```

2) yarn node -list - after starting of the first spark-shell - I got to the spark-shell console

```
Total Nodes:2
         Node-Id         Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
cassandra-node-2:43961 RUNNING  cassandra-node-2:8042 2
cassandra-node-1:36905 RUNNING  cassandra-node-1:8042 0
```

3) after I start second spark-shell, the output is same as in 2) and second shell is giving me:

```
[root@spark-master /]# spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2018-09-04 10:56:14 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

And no additional output as it is stuck.

App attempt for the second spark-shell in hadoop backend says:

```
Total Outstanding Resource Requests: memory:896, vCores:1
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `yarn node -list` for 3 scenarios. a) Before running any spark application. b) After start 1 spark-submit but before starting 2nd Spark submit. c) When 1st spark-submit is running and 2nd spark-submit is stuck.

Comment: @prakharjain added what you want, it is about spark-shell, not spark-submit.